# CucumberJS only shows diagnostic codes after ESM upgrade

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

We've recently upgraded our test suite to ESM rather than CommonJS. This involved a few things such as setting the following Node options

```
--experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm
```

Setting the `type` in `package.json` to `module` et al.

Everything works fine, until I introduce an error in one of the step definition files. It can be any error, but in this case, it's using a property that doesn't exist on an interface, such as:

```
interface Foo {
  bar string
}

const f: Foo = { invalid: '' }
```

In this case, when using `runCucumber`, we get an `ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION` error. If we add a `catch` to `runCucumber`, all we get back is a TypeScript diagnostic code:

```
{ diagnosticCodes: [ 2353 ] }
```

This code does point to the actual error when we look at [the list of TypeScript diagnostic codes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json) but we'd expect to see the actual error.

Here's how we're calling Cucumber

```
const config: ILoadConfigurationOptions = {
  file: 'cucumber.mjs',
}
const { runConfiguration } = await loadConfiguration(config)
const run = await runCucumber(runConfiguration).catch(console.error)
```

Here's the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true
  }
}
```

And here's the command to run the test suite

```
yarn component:gen-org-tests && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm --no-warnings index.ts
```

(index.ts contains the `runCucumber` step)

Looking in to the CucumberJS code, I can see this step that loads each file

```
await import((0, node_url_1.pathToFileURL)(path).toString());
```

and it appears it's here where it fails to load the file and exits.